# How to use labels inside of a control-row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a Boostrap to layout a form with horizontal row inputs (a la "control-row") but have labels positioned *above* the form input.  See the layout below for an example.

Is this possible with Boostrap?  I'm trying to avoid resorting to a million row/span# divs, but can't find another way of implementing this without a lot of custom CSS.  My current plan is to test out using tables :/  Please save me from that fate!

```
LABEL1      LABEL2
| Input |   | Input |

LABEL 3
| Long input         |

LABEL 4      LABEL 5
| Input |   | Input |
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2321/ - too many divs/spans?

Comment: You might want to edit the title of your question, since it says, BOOstrap (a Halloween pun, perhaps?), @user1644447

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this accomplished without the use of tables, using a combination of control-row and control-group classes.

```
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="controls-row">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="first-name" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="first-name" name="FirstName" />
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="middle-initial" class="control-label">M.I.:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="middle-initial" name="MiddleInitial" class="input-mini" />
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="last-name" class="control-label">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="last-name" name="LastName" />
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-row">
         <div class="control-group">
            <label for="ssn" class="control-label">Social Security Number:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="ssn" name="SocialSecurityNumber" />
            </div>                
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="dob" class="control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
            <div class="controls input-append">
                <input type="text" id="dob" name="DateOfBirth" />
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
</form>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

In order to get it to work correctly though (since control-group divs are `display: block;`, I had to override that class and add a `vertical-align: top;` with the following):

```
.control-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's how it turned out: http://jsfiddle.net/bhGyz/